# Adding a method to an imported class

Tags: java, android

I need to add a method to a class that I have imported in java. So more specifically I need to add a togglePlayPause() method to MediaPlayer. I am using Android Studio.

Comment: Create a custom class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding the method by creating a custom class that extends the MediaPlayer. Create the method within that class and you'll be able to create an instace of MediaPlayer with your wanted method. However, not all classes can be extended / inherited.